# How to Explicitly tells HTTP protocol version when using fetch api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

recently I'm stumbled into a problem which is my back-end server cannot responding preflight request that has been sent with SPDY or HTTP.2 protocol. It can only accept HTTP.1.1 protocol as a request.

Based on that situation can I use fetch API or XMLHttpRequest to explicitly send request with HTTP.1.1 protocol?

Your answer is very much welcomed. thank you :)

Comment: how is your back end server written in such a way that it serves http/2.0 but can't handle http/2.0 requests? i.e. what http server are you using?

Comment: What I'm saying is, the simplest (only) solution is to make sure the HTTP server never serves HTTP/2.0 if it can't handle HTTP/2.0 requests - that way the browser will never make the mistake of making such a request

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply. Right now I'm using libwebsocket web server (lwsws) as my server. Do you have any experience around that library?